# Adding a button to a list element which displays the remaining elements when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list with 5 list items. The second list item has a button after the text. When the button is clicked, the remaining list items should be displayed. But currently, the remaining items are displayed as a sub list, which is not what I am aiming for. I want the remaining items to be the part of the main list. This is how the list looks currently:[image]

This is the code:

```
<strong><span style="font-weight: bolder;">Level 1</span></strong><br />
My list:
<ul>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2<button id="button">Button Text</button>
    <div id="infodiv" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>Element 3</li>
        <li>Element 4.</li>
        <li>Element 5</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any leads are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you want :

```
<strong><span style="font-weight: bolder;">Level 1</span></strong><br />
My list:
<ul>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2<button id="button">Button Text</button></li>
    <div id="infodiv" class="list-group-item" style="display:none;">
        <li>Element 3</li>
        <li>Element 4.</li>
        <li>Element 5</li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#button').on('click',function(i, el){
        if($('#infodiv').is(':visible')){
        $('#infodiv').hide();
    }else{
        $('#infodiv').show();
    }
});
```

See [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u09yg5hL/1/)

What we are doing is is showing or hiding your **#infodiv** depending on if it is currrently visible or not. We also changed your html to remove the  in your sublist to not have another bullet list inside your list.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the HTML formatting automatically changes when I do the same thing in Qualtrics?

Comment: Hi, sorry I do not know qualtrics at all, can't really help you there without taking a huge guess

Answer (score 1):

Your items are displayed as sublist because you have a `ul` element inside the top list. If you want all list items to be displayed as a single list then remove the 2 `ul` as follows:

```
<strong><span style="font-weight: bolder;">Level 1</span></strong><br />
My list:
<ul>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2<button id="button">Button Text</button></li>
    <li class="showhide">Element 3</li>
    <li class="showhide">Element 4.</li>
    <li class="showhide">Element 5</li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also wrapping some `li`'s inside a `div` is not great semantically. Lastly you need to an on click event handler to the button (I'm assuming you're not using any frontend framework just Vanilla Javascript):

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
        <strong><span style="font-weight: bolder;">Level 1</span></strong><br />
        My list:
        <ul>
                <li>Element 1</li>
                <li>Element 2<button id="button">Button Text</button></li>
                <li class="showhide">Element 3</li>
                <li class="showhide">Element 4.</li>
                <li class="showhide">Element 5</li>
                </li>
        </ul>

    <script>
        document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(event) {
            const lis = document.getElementsByClassName('showhide')
            for (const li of lis) {
                li.style.display = li.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, in this case the remaining items are not hidden at first. I want them to be hidden until the button is clicked.

Comment: then you need to add some class to the `ul` elements you want show/hidden and an on click handler to the button which will change the class of the `ul` elements. Actually they're already wrapped in a `div` with `infodiv` id so just change the style of the div on click